# IdentityServer4 and ASP.NET Core 2.0

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, identityserver4, asp.net-core-2.0

I must be missing something but I cannot see it.
I have created a new 'empty' ASP.NET Core 2.0 Project
I added EF Core 2.0 and EF Core 2.0 Identity
I then try to add IdentityServer4 2.0 rc1 and I get a package restore failure with the following error message:

> Error occurred while restoring NuGet packages: Sequence contains more
>   than one matching element

There is no code in this project so I am completely confused.

Here is the csproj file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="wwwroot\" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="IdentityServer4" Version="2.0.0-rc1-update1" />
    <PackageReference Include="IdentityServer4.AspNetIdentity" Version="2.0.0-rc1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="NETStandard.Library" Version="2.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="2.0.0" />
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools" Version="2.0.0" />
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="2.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Here is my call to NuGet.org from the Package Manager Console:

> PM> Install-Package IdentityServer4.AspNetIdentity -Version 2.0.0-rc1
>   -Prerelease   GET https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration3-gz-semver2/identityserver4.aspnetidentity/index.json
>   OK
>   https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration3-gz-semver2/identityserver4.aspnetidentity/index.json
>   484ms Restoring packages for
>   D:\ProtoTypes\IdentityServer4\IdentityServer4\IdentityServer4.csproj...
>   Install-Package : Sequence contains more than one matching element At
>   line:1 char:1
>   + Install-Package IdentityServer4.AspNetIdentity -Version 2.0.0-rc1 -Pr ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand
>   Time Elapsed: 00:00:03.7728514 PM>

Comment: Try renaming your project ... maybe to MyIdentityServer4. This might be due to your project having the same name as one of the packages you are installing (IdentityServer4).

Comment: Right, now I feel like a complete ID10T!  Thank you @Peter

Answer (score 0):

Following are some changes that you will migrate your project to asp.net core 2.0.
Step 1:
Download asp.net core 2.0 gx64x for visual studio 2017 from the following link.https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/core
Step 2:
Download from Nuget packages or from package manager console
1-Install-Package IdentityServer4 -Version 2.0.0
2-Install-Package IdentityServer4.AspNetIdentity -Version 2.0.0-rc1-update2

Step 3:
Update Some Code in Csproj file.
    Before:
    netcoreapp1.1
    After:
    netcoreapp2.0

```
Before:
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies" Version="1.1.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics" Version="1.1.1" /> 
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="1.1.1" /> 
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="1.1.1" /> 
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="1.1.2" /> 
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration" Version="1.1.1" /> 
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel" Version="1.1.1" /> 
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" Version="1.1.1" /> 
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="1.1.1" /> 
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design" Version="1.1.1" /> 
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="1.1.0" /> 
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables" Version="1.1.1" /> 
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" Version="1.1.1" /> 
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets" Version="1.1.1" /> 
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging" Version="1.1.1" /> 
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console" Version="1.1.1" /> 
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="1.1.1" /> 
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions" Version="1.1.1" /> 
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink" Version="1.1.0" /> 
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="1.1.0" /> 
After:
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.0" />

Before:
<DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="1.0.0" />
<DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools" Version="1.0.0" />
<DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="1.0.0" />
 
After:
<DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="2.0.0" />
<DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools" Version="2.0.0" />
<DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="2.0.0" />
```

Step 4:
Update in Program.cs Class
    Before:
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var host = new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .UseIISIntegration()
            .UseStartup()
            .Build();
     
        host.Run();
    }
     
    After:
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BuildWebHost(args).Run();
    }
     
    public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
               .UseStartup()
               .Build();
Step 5:
Update in StartUp.cs

```
services.AddIdentityServer()
                    .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
                    .AddInMemoryPersistedGrants()
                    .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.GetIdentityResources())
                    .AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.GetApiResources())
                    .AddInMemoryClients(Config.GetClients())
                    .AddAspNetIdentity<ApplicationUser>();

        Before:
        app.UseIdentity();
        After:
        app.UseAuthentication();
```

Step 6:Changes in Manage Login ViewModel

```
Before:
public IList<AuthenticationDescription> OtherLogins { get; set; }
 
After:
public IList<AuthenticationScheme> OtherLogins { get; set; }
```

Step 7:
Changes in Manager Controller

```
Before:
var otherLogins = _signInManager
                  .GetExternalAuthenticationSchemes()
                  .Where(auth => userLogins
                                 .All(ul => auth.AuthenticationScheme != ul.LoginProvider))
                  .ToList();
 
After:
var otherLogins = (await _signInManager
                   .GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync())
                  .Where(auth => userLogins
                                 .All(ul => auth.Name != ul.LoginProvider))
                  .ToList();
```

Step 8:
Change sin Login.cshtml file
    Before:
    var loginProviders = SignInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemes().ToList();
     
    After:
    var loginProviders = (await SignInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();

```
Before:
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" 
        name="provider" value="@provider.AuthenticationScheme" 
        title="Log in using your @provider.DisplayName account">
    @provider.AuthenticationScheme
</button>
 
After:
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" 
        name="provider" value="@provider.Name" 
        title="Log in using your @provider.DisplayName account">
    @provider.Name
</button>
```